# How to automatically show a MKPointAnnotation title when a function is called?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm creating a function that when it's called, it will zoom in into the custom pin annotation coordinates and show its title and subtitle. The zoom part works fine, the only thing I can't do it's the title and subtitle part.

```
 private func addCustomPinRectoría1() {
        let pin1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        pin1.coordinate = coordinatesRectoría1
        pin1.title = "Rectoría"
        pin1.subtitle = "Parada TigreBus"
        map.addAnnotation(pin1)

  func selectAnnotation(_ vc: ContentViewController, didSelectLocationWith coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?) {
        guard let coordinates = coordinates else {
            return
        }
        map.removeAnnotations(map.annotations)
        let selectedPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        selectedPin.coordinate = coordinates
        map.addAnnotation(selectedPin)

        // Here is where I need to display the pin's title and subtitle automatically

        map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: coordinates,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.008, longitudeDelta: 0.008)),
                      animated: true)
        
    }
```

I don't know if this is useful, but I'll also leave this part of the code:

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
            return nil
        }
        var annotationView = map.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "custom")
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "custom")
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "TigreBusParada")
        annotationView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 100)
        return annotationView
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select annotation after adding it to mapView. Here is the code.

```
func selectAnnotation(_ vc: ContentViewController, didSelectLocationWith coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?) {
    guard let coordinates = coordinates else {
        return
    }
    map.removeAnnotations(map.annotations)
    let selectedPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    selectedPin.coordinate = coordinates
    map.addAnnotation(selectedPin)
    
    //add this line to show the title and subtitle
    map.selectAnnotation(selectedPin, animated: false)
    
    map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: coordinates,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.008, longitudeDelta: 0.008)),
                  animated: true)
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, do you know how can I show completely  my pin's titles? Because some of them are too long, they don't fit on the screen